# General solution to $\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}u(x,y)=\frac{\partial^m}{\partial y^m}u(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I have never taken a Partial Differential Equations course, so bare with me. I want to find the general solution to $$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}u(x,y)=\frac{\partial^m}{\partial y^m}u(x,y)$$out of curiosity (where $n$ and $m$ are positive integers). To do this, set $u(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$, so the PDE could be re-written as $f^{(n)}(x)=g^{(m)}(y)$, and the only way functions of $x$ and $y$ are equal is if they are constant. So a general solution to the PDE is $u(x,y)=c\left(\frac{x^n}{n!}+\frac{y^m}{m!}\right)$, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. To make this even more general, we could add arbitrary polynomials of $x$ and $y$ with degrees $n-1$ and $m-1$ respectively. My question is whether $u(x,y)=c\left(\frac{x^n}{n!}+\frac{y^m}{m!}\right)+p_{n-1}(x)+p_{m-1}(y)$ (where $p_k$ is an arbitrary polynomial of degree $k$ with constant coefficients) is as general as we can get. My substitution at the beginning restricts $u$ to a specific set of functions.

Edit: To make things simple, I want only real-valued solutions. Also, after reading the comments, the solution could be generalized to $u(x,y)=c\left(\frac{x^n}{n!}+\frac{y^m}{m!}\right)+p_{n-1}(x)+p_{m-1}(y)+p_{\min(m,n)-1}(x+y)+e^{x+y}$

Comment: What about $u(x,y)=f(x+y)$?

Comment: @podiki How could I use that substitution?

Comment: seems that any polynomial in $(x+y)$ with degree less than $min(m,n)$ would do the trick.

Comment: $\exp(x+y)$ is another solution and if you also consider complex valued functions so is $\exp(\lambda (x+y))$ with $\lambda^{n-m}=1$